# Phonegap ios : Initailly load camera into a div

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, camera

I am developing a phonegap ios application. I need camera to be on initially when page is loaded.

Now on clicking the div, camera is loaded in a new screen with two buttons "retake" and "use".if click on "use" button then the captured snap will be appended to img with id "preview"

code is,

```
function onCamera() {
   navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {
       alert('get picture failed');
   },{
       quality: 50,
       destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
       sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA
    });      
}

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {       
   $("#preview").attr({
       src: imageURI,
       title: "cam",
       alt: "cam image"                     
   });          
}


<div onclick="onCamera()">
    <img src="Images/camera.png" style="width:50px; height:50px;"/>
</div>

<div class="cam">
    <img id="preview" src="css/empty.png" style="width:100%; height:300px;"  />                
</div>
```

How can i make the camera load to div with id "preview" when the page is loaded initially?

Please Help, Thanks.